# autoHotkey close browser if browser is already open

Tags: autohotkey

If browser is not already open. make the browser open.
If browser is already open. make the browser close.

I've found a script but this does not close the browser

```
!f::
firefox = C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe
IfWinExist, firefox     ; Title of the prog
    {
    WinActivate
    WinClose
    }
else
    {
    Run, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe "github.com"
    Run,  C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe "stackoverflow.com"
    }
```

How can I close the program already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
!f::
firefox = C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe
IfWinExist, "ahk_exe firefox.exe"     ; Executable name
    {
    WinActivate
    WinClose
    }
else
    {
    Run, C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe "github.com"
    Run,  C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe "stackoverflow.com"
    }
```

Comment: 1) You don't need to store the path in a variable. 2) `WinActivate` is not necessary to close a window 3) Add  `return` at the end to terminate the hotkey's thread.